# Downgrade Bios on Dell prescison

Tags: bios

I have a Dell Precision 5540 with Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS. The battery was completely fine. After a week of Bios update the battery is completely dead. I am thinking about downgrading the BIOS (recent 1.23.0) to the previous one.

Has anyone tried it? Is it recommended? If so then how can I go about doing so?

Comment: Your guess is unsupported by data. Don't do it.